# In Haskell why does the |> operator give out of scope error in this example?

Tags: haskell, scope

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Main where
  import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
  import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
  import qualified Data.ByteString as B
  import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
  import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
  import qualified Data.Vector as VB
  import qualified Data.List as L

  (|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
  x |> f = f x

  main :: IO ()
  main =
    let
        parse (s :: ByteString) = s |> L.unfoldr (C.readInt . C.dropWhile (== ' '))
        solve (l :: Int) (ars :: VB.Vector ByteString) =
          let
              (n :: V.Vector (Int, Int)) = V.fromList [(x,y) | x <- [0..l-1], y <- [x+1..l-1]]
          in
              n
    in do
        [n,l :: Int] <- parse <$> B.getLine
        (ars :: VB.Vector ByteString) <- VB.replicateM n B.getLine
        ars 
        |> solve l 
        |> print
```

The compiler complains that `l` is not in scope for some reason here. Why is that?

```
Not in scope: `l'
```

Also the reason the code looks like that is because I've just figured out what the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension does. It should be in the language proper, and in the beginner tutorials. It would have saved me a lot of pain over the past few weeks.

Comment: That's not the error I get. Can you give the actual program you're testing and exactly what compiler error you get?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited the example so the error triggers. Also it seems when I write it out as `ars |> solve l |> print` in one line, the example works.

Comment: You're still missing imports, for example.

Comment: Added the full example.

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing `let (n :: Type) = expr in n` where you could simply do (AFAICT) `expr :: Type`, in fact you could just provide the type signature for the function and be done: `solve :: Int -> VB.Vector ByteString -> V.Vector (Int, Int); solve l ars = V.fromList [(x,y) | ...]`

Comment: @Bakuriu It does not mean much in the example above, but the top level type annotations like the one you've written above are really, really horrible. They get in the way massively when refactoring code. Also being able to do local type annotation in functions means that they are possible to do in lambda functions as well. That simple feature might have just tripled my productivity in one swoop because now I do not have to get all the types right at once and can incrementally interact with the compiler. I should have made figuring out how to do this a priority a month ago.

Comment: @Bakuriu Also for long chains of expressions, reading top to bottom and chaining the functions using `|>` as with F# is far superior to function composition in the opposite direction using the `.` operator. `.` should only be used for one liners. I'll make it a resolution not to use the `.` operator again. I blame the linter of pushing me in the wrong direction in terms of style.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic Note that you can add typed holes in type signatures: `solve :: _ -> _ -> V.Vector (Int, Int)` the compiler will then perform type inference and tell you the type associated with those holes. This means that using type signatures you can still add types incrementally.  Moreover *not* putting type signatures will sometimes break your code (e.g. the type inferred is actually too generic and you get ambiguity errors, or due to monomorphism restriction is less polymorphic than you thought).

Comment: @Bakuriu Actually, I hadn't known about typed holes. I'd still prefer the locally scoped variables solution as it does not require me to have the name of the function on two places. And you can't use the top-level form in lambda functions. You'd have to pull them out and use a named function instead.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic Lambas usually do not require a type signature, since they ought to be very simple.  By the way: note that you cannot express all possibly types in the way you are doing. For example if you had a function with type `Ord a => a -> [a] -> Bool` you wouldn't be able to write `f (x :: Ord a => a) (xs :: Ord a => [a])`.  So what you are using only works for monomorphic types. Explicit types are especially useful when dealing with complex *polymorphic* types, as those are the ones that can give troubles to the type inferencer, rendering your technique quite useless in most cases.

Comment: @Bakuriu I see, that is good to know. I do not think I have ever needed to deal with complex polymorphic types. Currently, I am just trying to deal with HackerRank problems, rather than write libraries in Haskell. My issue with it are more of the debugging kind. Actually, if it was not for the linter, I would not have guessed what `ScopedTypeVariables` even do just by looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. Either of the following work.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import qualified Data.Vector as VB
import Data.List as L
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
x |> f = f x

main :: IO ()
main =
  let
    parse (s :: ByteString) = s |> L.unfoldr (C.readInt . C.dropWhile (== ' '))
    solve (l :: Int) (ars :: VB.Vector ByteString) =
      let
        (n :: V.Vector (Int, Int)) = V.fromList [(x,y) | x <- [0..l-1], y <- [x+1..l-1]]
      in
        n
  in do
    [n,l :: Int] <- parse <$> B.getLine
    (ars :: VB.Vector ByteString) <- VB.replicateM n B.getLine
    ars |> solve l |> print
```

-

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import qualified Data.Vector as VB
import Data.List as L
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
x |> f = f x

main :: IO ()
main =
  let
    parse (s :: ByteString) = s |> L.unfoldr (C.readInt . C.dropWhile (== ' '))
    solve (l :: Int) (ars :: VB.Vector ByteString) =
      let
        (n :: V.Vector (Int, Int)) = V.fromList [(x,y) | x <- [0..l-1], y <- [x+1..l-1]]
      in
        n
  in do
    [n,l :: Int] <- parse <$> B.getLine
    (ars :: VB.Vector ByteString) <- VB.replicateM n B.getLine
    ars |>
      solve l |>
      print
```

Comment: Er, sorry, but please see the edit. `ars |> solve l |> print` should be in 3 lines, I accidentally pasted the correct thing. Now I see that that I have a simple indentation problem. Yeah, this is it.